# Designing a python kde widget

Tags: python, linux, widget, kde-plasma, plasmoid

I just started trying to figure out how to make a kde widget using python i finished some quick tutorials (https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma4/Python/Using_widgets) but i want to design a much more complicated gui and i would like the help of a designing tool for widgets in python, is there such a thing ? or something that could make my life easier than trying to design the whole thing by code ?

Comment: Well there is QtCreator (KDE is based on the Qt toolkit), but I am not sure how well this works in combination with python, since the typical language for KDE components is c++.

Comment: I suggest to look at [this stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915633/please-point-me-to-good-documentation-about-qt-layouts-for-plasma-development)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not terribly mistaken, there are no KDE widgets. KDE uses Qt to create GUI's so you'd need to see the [Qt Designer](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Using_Qt_Designer) program.

There's no reason you couldn't design UIs in GTK, which is supported too in most KDE environments. There you can use the [Anjuta IDE](http://anjuta.org), which can use the [Glade UI designer](https://glade.gnome.org/) for the actual graphical layout.

All these packages should be available in your repository.